# TreeItem ClickHandler in GWT

Tags: gwt

With the standard GWT 2.0.3 API, how do you add a Clickhandler to the TreeItem? I'm hoping to implement asynchronous calls to the server that will retrieve the resulting TreeItems that are expanded.

Unfortunately `FastTree` doesn't work in GXT applications. Therefore I'm back to the original step of needing to attach handlers to `TreeItem`s!

Are there any noticeable downfalls with this code:

```
Tree.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<TreeItem>()
{
    @Override
    public void onSelection(SelectionEvent event()
    {
        if(event.getSelectedItem == someTreeItem)
        {
            //Something
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With GWT's default `Tree`, there aren't handlers for specific `TreeItem`s, just one `SelectionHandler` for the entire tree:

```
tree.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<TreeItem>() {
  @Override
  public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<TreeItem> event) {
    TreeItem item = event.getSelectedItem();
    // expand the selected item
  }
});
```

However, the [GWT incubator](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/)'s [`FastTree`](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/FastTree) was literally built just for what you're trying to do, lazy-load the tree as items are expanded, so I would start there. Feel free to ask more questions if you have any.

Comment: How do I know if the user clicked the root of TreeZ?

Comment: Currently `event.getSelectedItem()` returns `Object`, and not `TreeItem`. You have to cast it to `TreeItem`: `TreeItem item = (TreeItem) event.getSelectedItem();`.

Answer (score -1):

```
// First create a new treeitem-class with a new method:
public class TreeItemAdv extends TreeItem {
    protected void doSelectionAction() {
        // TODO: The child should overwrite this method!
        System.out.println("The child should overwrite this method!");
    }
}
```

---

```
...
    // define your tree:
    Tree tree = new Tree();
    tree.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<TreeItem>() {
        @Override
        public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<TreeItem> event) {               
            TreeItemAdv item = (TreeItemAdv) event.getSelectedItem();
            item.doSelectionAction(); // do item-specific stuff
        }
    });

    // define and add your items:
    TreeItemAdv ti1 = new TreeItemAdv() {
        @Override
        protected void doSelectionAction() {
            // TODO: Do some stuff.
            System.out.println("1: Here I am.");
        }           
    };      
    ti1.setText("Item 1");      
    tree.addItem(ti1);
    // and an other item:
    TreeItemAdv ti2 = new TreeItemAdv() {
        @Override
        protected void doSelectionAction() {
            // TODO: Do some stuff.
            System.out.println("2: Here I am.");
        }           
    };      
    ti2.setText("Item 2");      
    tree.addItem(ti2);
...
```